# Can declare an array to variable, but undefined when trying to concat() instead

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code which works as expected:

```
this.filteredCampaigns = this.allCampaigns.filter((item) => item.status!.includes(filterConditions))
//this.filteredCampaigns is of type Campaign[] | null and allallCampaigns is of type 
 product.Campaign[]
```

the.filteredCampaingns is empty, while the allCampaigns stores all data. When I try to concat it, it returns undefined and no compiler errors:

```
this.filteredCampaigns.concat(this.allCampaigns.filter((item) => item.status!.includes(filterConditions)))  //returns undefined
```

When I instead try push, I get an error

```
Type 'Campaign[]' has no properties in common with type 'Campaign'.ts(2559)

this.filteredCampaigns.push(this.allCampaigns.filter((item) => 
 item.status!.includes(filterConditions)))  //returns undefined
```

How to solve this? I can only declare the value of the array, but I need to add/push more data in to it which does not work.

In the following order:

```
this.filteredCampaigns = this.allCampaigns.filter((item) => item.description?.toLowerCase().includes(filteredString))

 this.filteredCampaigns.concat(this.allCampaigns.filter((item) => item.type?.toLowerCase().includes(filteredString)));
```

Comment: It's not clear what order you're calling this code in. What is the value of `this.filteredCampaigns` before you call `.concat()` or `.push()`?

Comment: Updated my post. No combination of .concat() or .push() works. Initially I declared the value, and then .concat() (returned undefined). Since it didnt work I tried .push() which game me compilations error instead. If I instead declare it with the same value I tried to push/concat it will work.

Comment: Shouldn't you spread your Array when used as an argument for `push()`?

Comment: Also, `concat` doesn't alter the arrays it's being called on, nor the arguments provided - it returns a shallow copy. Are you storing the result of that call anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error on `push()` because you're attempting to push an Array as a single element onto the other Array, which Typescript is rightfully calling out. You should use `push()` like this instead:

```
this.filteredCampaigns.push(...this.allCampaigns.filter((item) => 
 item.status!.includes(filterConditions)))
```

Using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) means that you're pushing the separate elements of that Array onto the target Array.

As far as the `concat()` problem, it's because you're not assigning the result of the `concat()` operation to anything. `concat()` does not operate on the Array it's called on (it doesn't operate "in place") but returns a value ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)). If you want to use `concat()`, assign the value to the target Array:

```
this.filteredCampaigns = this.filteredCampaigns.concat(this.allCampaigns.filter((item) => item.type?.toLowerCase().includes(filteredString)));
```